# Writing applications with clean URL

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, clean-urls

I want to display articles in a website in the following manner

```
example.com/articles/23/thetitle

ie  example.com/articles/{id}/{title}
```

For each request, what actually matters is the id. I will display the article corresponding to the id, the title is shown for readability. Now the problem is when the user edits the url in the browser, say from `example.com/articles/23/thetitle` to `example.com/articles/23/xyz` and reloads, the same content is loaded with the new url.

How do i get around this? How can I get my URL to be displayed as `example.com/articles/23/thetitle` for a an entry  `example.com/articles/23/{anything}`

I had a look into [URLrewriting](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). but it doesn't seem to be the solution for me.

The only solution i can think about is doing it from javascript, but that IMHO is dirty.

I am using Spring MVC. Thanks in advance

PS:
To put it in one sentence, I want it to work the way it works in SO. If we edit the question number and reload, the new title is loaded.

Here is a code sample of how I am currently fetching an article

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/{title}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public 
String loadArticle(HttpServletRequest request,
        @PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    //get the article
    model.addAttribute("article", article);
    return "article";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a servlet that checks the URL and sends an HTTP redirect response code (method `sendRedirect` it `HttpServletResponse`)

Comment: An http filter set to process all /articles/* URLs. When a request arrives, it checks if the URL in the request is valid. If it is not, send a redirect to the correct URL, so the browser requests the right URL (which will make the browser change the URL). You can do logic in the servlets, too, but it makes more sense with a filter.

Comment: Are you telling me to do a response.sendRedirect("example.com/articles/23/thetitle") in case the title is different?

Comment: Ok. Makes sense :) So in the filter or servlet, I have to first check if the title passed is correct, if not I have a to redirect it with the new title. Isn't that right?

Comment: Yes. I would do that in a filter because a) it is more clean and modular and b) I am not sure if the URL rewritter will change the URL in the request to the servlet when it processes it (you can check that easily, though).

Comment: Additionally, I have been checking the link you provided. While the documentation is a little obscure, maybe `class-rule` can do just that for you. Sadly, links to the example are broken.